# Socket encrytion form base64string byte array

Tags: c#, sockets, byte, aes

There a section comment out when I run it the way it
is now a get a in64basestring error in my decryption function

when run with comment out temp variable I get
Invailid block size

the fist thing by aes decryption function does in
convert frombase 64 string

I have tested encryption function and it works 
also I have tested the decryption function
local in my logn and it works

I just started C# recently
and have never used sockets

Thanks for the help in advance

private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);

```
            if (size > 0)
            {

                byte[] receivedData = new byte[1464];

                receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                //attemp to fix string 64


                ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

                //UTF8Encoding eEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();



                string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
               //byte to string

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //string temp;
                                                                                      /////trying a temp variable
                //temp = Convert.ToBase64String(eEncoding.GetBytes(receivedMessage));
                //string result = Decrypt(temp);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                string result = Decrypt(receivedMessage);
                //string result = Decrypt2(receivedMessage);
                listMessage.Items.Add("User2: " + (result));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you transmit a message of size N bytes, the receiving end when issuing a read can get:

- Less than N bytes
- N bytes
- More than N bytes

So you may not have a complete message or, have parts of 2 messages therefore when you go to decrypt, that's why you're getting errors.

There are two general methods to working with socket messages - those with a prefix stating the message length followed by the messaage; and those using a defined delimiter to indicate start/stop of message.

For prefix based messages I use the following class to track received data:

```
public class ReceiveState
{
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[1024]; //buffer for network i/o
    public int DataSize = 0; //data size to be received by the server
    public bool DataSizeReceived = false; //whether prefix was received
    public MemoryStream Data = new MemoryStream(); //place where data is stored
    public Socket Client;   //client socket
}
```

So my call to receive data looks like:

```
client.BeginReceive(rState.Buffer, 0, rState.Buffer.Length,
SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(socketReadCallBack),
rState);
```

Check out this SO answer for more info on the code I use: [Socket OnData event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870057/socket-ondata-event/12870826#12870826)