# How to implement sockets on the server side C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, tcpclient

I'm learning to work with sockets, and every example in every article or book demonstrates how a server should work using a desktop console or wpf application. The authors usually say that *the same code can be easily implemented on the server*.

Maybe it's easy, but still -- how? Do I have to use WCF or maybe something else? Is there any good book which can help me to become the lord of sockets?

Comment: Hardly you would need to use sockets directly, just google wcf tutorials

Answer (score 0):

The "same code on the server" comment means you're really developing a communications interface protocol. You send messages in a particular way, and expect to receive in the same way. Eg. fixed length messages vs agreed terminator; how message data is formatted etc.

If you put your code into it's own set of classes you can then host your code in any sort of application - console, wpf as you've stated but also.. windows services. In my case i've got it so that running the app in debug mode runs winforms, but as release mode runs as a service.

The answer to this SO question has some useful links.

[Chat service application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345860/chat-service-application/14349690#14349690)

I highly recommend Vadym's posts and Stephen Cleary's nito documentation.